# Quickest way to partially restore a mongodb instance from AWS snapshots?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4, wiredtiger

I have multiple large mongodb clusters running mongodb 3.4 configured with wiredtiger. I would like to set up standalone instances with just a few DBs from these clusters, all on the same EC2 instance.

What I've done so far is to create snapshots of the disks (DB and journal) on a replica from each of the clusters. I then create EBS volumes from these snapshots and mount them on the same EC2 instance.

My problem is the time the restoration takes; though I want just 5-10% of the original data, I have a long process of `chown`ing the data, followed by a lengthy DB startup of each of the standalone mongodb instances and then dropping the majority of the DBs. This process takes a few hours which I'd like to expedite.

I went with starting from snapshots rather than performing dump+restore because I was hoping it would be quicker.

Given the fact that I want to get rid of the majority of the DBs (so I don't care about corruption related to them), is there a method someone can recommend that will leave me with just the DBs I need?

Comment: If you need only part of data (and databases), why you don't bring up just one of those shards as a standalone copy? (not as a cluster)

Comment: The better way in AWS is, Take an AMI of the primary server. launch an instance from the AMI, Remove replica set in conf file. Then drop unwanted databases.

Comment: @JJussi the data is sensitive, I need to remove it before using the instances.

Comment: @SQLadmin I think that creating the snapshot is equivalent to making an AMI based on the primary server. I'll still have the extra time of starting up the instance and dropping the DBs.

Comment: Hmm.. How about bring new empty mongodb node up and then use `db.cloneDatabase()` or `db.cloneCollection(from, collection, query)`  command to clone there only what you need.

Comment: @JJussi thanks for pointing that out to me! Though I'm not sure  transferring all that data by network will be quicker than what I already have. Another downside is the possible impact this will have on the replica; a nice aspect about working from a volume snapshot is that the replica just needs to be stopped just for long enough to start the snapshot creation (and even then it can take an hour for it to be in sync again).

Comment: You don't need to stop replica if you do LVM snapshot, as long as OpLog is at the same volume.